# Powershell script on startup stopping .mp3

Tags: powershell

I'm running into an issue when I boot my PC the .mp3 file stops once the system speech is completed. I'd like it to run a little longer. Syntax below.

```
'Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationCore
$mediaPlayer = New-Object system.windows.media.mediaplayer
$mediaPlayer.open('C:\Users\avery\Videos\01 - Highway To Hell.mp3')
$mediaPlayer.Play()

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.speech
$speak = New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
$tts.Rate   = -2 # -10 to 10; -10 is slowest, 10 is fastest
$speak.Speak('Welcome home sir. You will need to pay attention the entire duration. With every 
passing hour I will monitor your actions. Enjoy your time sir. Thank you for your time today and I 
hope you accomplish everything you set your mind to. The world is your oyster.')'
```

It runs perfectly I'm just not sure why it stops short.  When I run it in Powershell ISE it continues to play the .mp3 but on startup it stops early.  I'd like to add an argument to play it longer, or trick it into thinking the speech is longer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you probably could insert a wait loop after starting to play the mp3, to see if the music has finished or not. Something like:

```
$mediaPlayer = New-Object system.windows.media.mediaplayer
$mediaPlayer.open('C:\Users\avery\Videos\01 - Highway To Hell.mp3')
$mediaPlayer.Play()
while (!($mediaPlayer.MediaEnded)) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
}
$mediaPlayer.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sleep until to current position of the media player control reaches the total duration of the song:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Speech

$mp = New-Object System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer
$mp.Open('C:\Users\avery\Videos\01 - Highway To Hell.mp3')
$mp.Play()

$speak = New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
$speak.Rate   = -2 # -10 to 10; -10 is slowest, 10 is fastest
$speak.Speak('Welcome home sir. You will need to pay attention the entire duration. With every 
passing hour I will monitor your actions. Enjoy your time sir. Thank you for your time today and I 
hope you accomplish everything you set your mind to. The world is your oyster.')

# Sleep until the songs over
do{
  Write-Host "Waiting for the song to end..."
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}while($mp.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan -and $mp.Position -lt $mp.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan)

Write-Host "Done!"
```